# COM Addin does not load in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, clickonce

I have traced and read a lot of post similar to this issue but seems neither one of them fit my case.

The user installed my addin successfully but the excel seems doesn't load the addin (because there is no error prompt and the addin does not list in active/inactive/disabled items). However other user on the same machine does not have the same problem.

**Background info:**

Environment: Windows 10, Excel 2016

COM Addin developed in (C#/VSTO) and published with Clickonce.

The addin does not load only on one user of a machine, the other users on the same machine does not have the problem.

The addin can be installed successfully.

The registry shows the addin LoadBehavior: 3, load on startup.

The addin is not list anywhere in Excel Options > Addins > Active , Inactive , Disabled , COM Addins.

No installation error and runtime error is prompted even with VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0.

Tried to uninstall the addin, clear the registry and reinstall the addin. Same problem still happen on that user.

Comment: what is your question or problem ?

Comment: the user does not have the COM addin available on the excel even the installation is successful, however another on the same machine does not have the problem

Answer (score 0):

If there are no errors displayed with alerts not suppressed, then Word isn't even trying to load the add-in. The user may have all add-ins disabled. Check File > options > Trust Center> Trust Center Settings > Add-ins > Disable all application add-ins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked the Trust Center Settings, "Disable all Application Add-ins" is unchecked. And I have tested with a normal case, if the option is checked, all the add-ins should be disabled and list under "Disabled Application Add-ins".